# What is this rambling/climbing plant with small leaves?

Tags: identification, weeds, vines

It's grown up my unused bench and I think it actually looks pretty. Is it dangerous, noxious, or uncontrollable? It's been there for almost a year and hasn't flowered. It grows up trees (I try to cut it down when it does). It makes a large tangled shrub at the bottom.

**Photos:** (click to enlarge)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd have to agree with the first answer, Asparagus asparagoides, or is it aspergolites? It came up in my yard after the re landscaping and began climbing up the trellis with the Geraniums. I didn't know what it was but it is pretty. But I'm assuming now that it will try to kill the Geranium so I will pull or dig it out. Thank you J. Musser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is [*Asparagus asparagoides*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asparagus_asparagoides), a vigorous rambler from South Africa. It has naturalized and become an invasive weed in other places in the world (such as California, Australia, New Zealand), after being introduced as an ornamental/landscape plant and florists plant.

Identifying features include:

- The 'leaves' (technically called phylloclades), they are actually flattened stem segments, and show the parallel venation typical of monocots.
- Rambling/climbing growth habit
- Underground tubers (they will be much better developed under bright lighting conditions on mature plants)
- Small white flowers, followed by berries (again, more commonly on mature plants in plenty of sun).

Depending were you live, this may be considered an invasive weed in your area. If it begins to flower and fruit, I'd recommend removing it, so that it doesn't begin moving into the surrounding neighborhood.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will be sure to remove it if it flowers, although it seems really tough to remove according to some websites.

Comment: There's not much info online considering it's a "Weed of National Significance" in Australia.

Comment: @J.Musser is this the same or related?  Tradescantia albiflora?  Wandering jew?  They've changed so many genus names.

Comment: I'd pull a bit up and plant in a pot with potting soil.  I love the purple of the species!

Comment: @stormy no, that is a very different species.

Comment: I feel better when there are at least 2 if not 3 different ID's.  Nice to have reference and other ideas with which to test for the best ID.  This is how I rationalize my wrong ID's!  Grins!

Comment: @stormy there is only one proper ID in any given case. But I agree, better to be sure